# existById in JpaRepository return NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, repository

I have an implemented interface extends from `JpaRepository`
when I use `repository.existById();`
and pass unavailable id in the database.

It returns `NullPointerException`, there is nothing saying anything about `NullPointer` in the documentation.

It's a boolean, why it return `NullPointerException`?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#existsById-ID-

My repository

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

    Boolean existsAccountByClientUsername(String username);

    Account findAccountByClientUsername(String username);
}
```

Test code that uses exsistByID

```
@Test
public void givenNotAvailableId_whenGetAccountById_thenThrowIllegalArgumentException() {
    Long id = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    IllegalArgumentException exception = Assertions
             .assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> accountService.getAccountById(id));
    Assertions.assertEquals("Id not found", exception.getMessage());
}
```

production code

```
@Service
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AccountService(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }
    public Optional<Account> getAccountById(Long id) {
        throwIfNotFoundId(id);
        return accountRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

`throwIfNotFoundId` method

```
private void throwIfNotFoundId(Long id) {
    if (!accountRepository.existsById(id)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Id not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Add full stack trace   for your error in post

Comment: also add more about your test code

Answer (score -2):

Do you have the stack trace of the null pointer?

I would say it is something not autowired up correctly that's throwing the null pointer.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment!

Comment: It won't let me comment, just trying to help

Comment: Well, then please gain reputation first by answering on questions that you can answer.